# Order of execution of DB2 query to append date in file name and generating FTP card

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

Could anyone please explain the order of execution of below query?

Below query is used to append the date to file name and generate the corresponding ftp card.

```
SELECT CHAR('close',80) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT CHAR('   /CSSC/Inbound/AP_MP_P2C_A47_Report/A47_"' ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),6,2) ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),9,2) ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),3,2) || '.TXT',80)
      FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT CHAR(
        'put ' ||
        X'27' ||
        'MCSP.WMCS11CD.OPENPOS.TABFILE.TEMP' ||
        X'27' ||
        ' +'
        ,80)
FROM
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT CHAR('ASCII',80) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT CHAR('quit',80)  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

The result is

```
ASCII                                                                           
put 'MCSP.WMCS11CD.OPENPOS.TABFILE.TEMP' +                                      
/CSSC/Inbound/AP_MP_P2C_A47_Report/A47_110914.TXT                                           
close                                                                           
quit
```

I understood the query but how it came in above order. if I change the line of query, it is giving another output (ie order matters)

Comment: In a relational database the order of a result set is not defined _unless_ there is an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: yes. but once I execute the above query I am getting the output in the order ASCII, put , close, quit. (This is the expected result, but curious to know what is controlling the order).One more thing to add is, if you look at the above query you can see order of UNIONs of query is different from that of result.    If I change the query by exchanging the places of UNIONs, I am getting result in different order. I have not used 'Order' clause too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mustaccio said, there is no order unless you provide an `ORDER BY` clause. Without that clause, the database engine will pick the "easiest" way to bring back the data. It's not even guaranteed to be the same order between two consecutive runs of the query.

If you need a specific order, then you should add a new field that provides the ordering, and use the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT text FROM (
    SELECT CHAR('ASCII',80), 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

        UNION ALL

    SELECT CHAR( 'put ' ||  X'27' ||
            'MCSP.WMCS11CD.OPENPOS.TABFILE.TEMP' ||
            X'27' || ' +' ,80), 2
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

        UNION ALL

    SELECT CHAR('   /CSSC/Inbound/AP_MP_P2C_A47_Report/A47_' || 
                VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT DATE, 'MMDDYY') || 
                '.TXT',80), 3
          FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CHAR('close',80), 4 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

        UNION ALL

    SELECT CHAR('quit',80), 5  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) AS A (text, num)
ORDER BY num
```

Not that I've changed your `DATE` substrings to a call to [`VARCHAR_FORMAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-179). This scalar function allows you to specify the format for how to convert a date type to a string type. I think it's a lot clearer than having to use substrings.

Comment: I have run it many times and it is giving me the same output. Also if the change the order of text in query, it is giving output with different order.

Comment: @B.K You ran _what_ many times? Are you referring to your query or to the query suggested by bhamby?

Answer (score 0):

to reiterate @mustaccio, nothing is controlling the order.

You are getting lucky in that the DB is choosing to output the results in the order as the DB sees that as the "easiest" or "cheapest" way to do it today.  I'm actually very surprised at the order it picked.  Guessing there was a lot of trial and error to get it ordered right.

That order could conceivably change with the installation of any given fix (PTF).

This is a very poor way to build an FTP script in my opinion.  But if you are going to do it, you should do it like so

```
with tbl (linenbr, stmt) as (
SELECT 4, CHAR('close',80) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, CHAR('   /CSSC/Inbound/AP_MP_P2C_A47_Report/A47_"' ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),6,2) ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),9,2) ||
         SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO),3,2) || '.TXT',80)
      FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CHAR(
        'put ' ||
        X'27' ||
        'MCSP.WMCS11CD.OPENPOS.TABFILE.TEMP' ||
        X'27' ||
        ' +'
        ,80)
FROM
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, CHAR('ASCII',80) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, CHAR('quit',80)  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT stmt from TBL
ORDER BY linenbr;
```